# Saving source code from the internet

Tags: subversion, web, version-control

How can I save all the documents from this adress to my PC?

https://svn.linuxsampler.org/svn/liblscp/trunk/

This is a package I need to build "Open Octave DAW" from source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems to be an SVN repository. So you can just check it out:

```
svn co https://svn.linuxsampler.org/svn/liblscp/trunk/
```

You need to have [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) installed (should be available via package manager on most systems)

Comment: What i get is a folder and if i get inside it and try to execute command `./configure` it does not work. Why is that? I tried to use this command allso in "src" subfolder and the same thing happens...

Comment: @71GA http://linuxsampler.org/faq.html#install